# mobileinit initSelector not working

Tags: jquery-mobile, select, select-menu

Using jQM 1.4, I am working on a custom `select` widget, with `[data-role='toggleselect']`, like so:

```
<select data-role="toggleselect">
    <option value="1">One</option>
    <option value="2">Two</option>
    <option value="3">Three</option>
</select>
```

For this, I need my `select` element to not be enhanced.  From what I have read in the jQM 1.4 API ***[here](http://api.jquerymobile.com/selectmenu/#option-initSelector)*** and understand, I should be able to use the following to prevent my `select` from being enhanced by the primary `mobile.selectmenu` widget:

```
$( document ).on( "mobileinit", function() {
    $.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.initSelector += ":not(:jqmData(role='toggleselect'))";
});
```

Here is my [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mrphuzz/f3jM3/) showing that this doesn't work.  My `select` element is still being enhanced.  And *yes*, this is placed after loading jQuery but before jQM.

For further experimentation, I hardcoded the following initSelector into the jQM-1.4.js file under the `mobile.selectmenu` widget:

```
initSelector: "select:not(:jqmData(role='slider')):not(:jqmData(role='flipswitch')):not(:jqmData(role='toggleselect'))"
```

When this is hardcoded, my `select` is *not* enhanced, thus works as expected.

Below is a copy/paste of my file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>mobile.toggleselect</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" />
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            $( document ).on( "mobileinit", function() {
                $.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.initSelector += ":not(:jqmData(role='toggleselect'))";
            });
        </script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page">
            <div data-role="header">
                <h3>mobile.toggleselect</h3>
            </div>
            <div data-role="content">
                <select data-role="toggleselect">
                    <option value="1">One</option>
                    <option value="2">Two</option>
                    <option value="3">Three</option>
                </select>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Again, if I download a local copy of the `jquery.mobile-1.4.0.js` file and hardcode the `initSelector` for `mobile.selectmenu`, it works as expected.

So... what am I missing?  Or is this a bug?

Comment: remove `.prototype` and it will work http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/f3jM3/1/ as `.prototype` is used with `.options`.

Comment: @Omar: Thanks, this worked.  My question then becomes: is the ___[API documentation](http://api.jquerymobile.com/selectmenu/#option-initSelector)___ wrong when it says to use `$.mobile.selectmenu.prototype.initSelector`?  Or do I just misunderstand what I read?

Comment: The same mistake on all widgets http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/sX3tr/

Comment: @Omar: Yup, I noticed that too.  I tested with other widgets and got the same (lack of) results.

Comment: I've report this issue to jQM team.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like a mistake in jQuery Mobile API 1.4 documentation.

To assign a custom *initSelector*

```
$.mobile.widget.initSelector = ".selector";
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/ayRqY/)**